# numpy - broadcasting an operation over dimensions on which two arrays match

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have two arrays, `x` and `y`, where `x.shape == (n, d)` and `y.shape == (k, d)`.

I'd like to produce an array z where `z.shape == (n, k)` and `z[i][j] = np.linalg.norm(x[i] - y[j])`.

Is there any reasonable, vectorized way to do this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.linalg.norm(np.expand_dims(x, 1) - y, axis=-1)`.

For example,

```
In [15]: d = 2                                                                                

In [16]: n = 3                                                                                

In [17]: k = 5                                                                                

In [18]: x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(n, d))                                            

In [19]: y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(k, d))                                            

In [20]: np.linalg.norm(np.expand_dims(x, 1) - y, axis=-1)                                    
Out[20]: 
array([[2.82842712, 5.        , 6.70820393, 4.        , 7.07106781],
       [8.94427191, 6.70820393, 1.        , 2.82842712, 7.07106781],
       [4.12310563, 3.16227766, 7.07106781, 5.38516481, 5.38516481]])
```

Check individually the values at [0,0] and [2, 3]:

```
In [21]: np.linalg.norm(x[0,:] - y[0,:])                                                      
Out[21]: 2.8284271247461903

In [22]: np.linalg.norm(x[2,:] - y[3,:])                                                      
Out[22]: 5.385164807134504
```